# 'hidden.bs.modal' lazy triggering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
var switchProductDetailsToCartModal = function (target){
    $('#productDetailsModal').modal('hide'); // 'hidden.bs.modal' was not triggered here

    $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel('pause');
    // 
}

//'hidden.bs.modal' handler triggered here and carousel steel cycling


$(function() {
    $('#productDetailsModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (){
        $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel('cycle');
    });
});
```

Does it normal behavior? Anyway how can I trigger 'hidden.bs.modal' handler immediately after `modal('hide')` ?

jquery-1.11.3, 
bootstrap3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a different event, `hide.bs.modal`.  This will fire immediately after the call to hide:

```
$('#productDetailsModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (){
  $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel('cycle');
});
```

From the Bootstrap [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events):

> **hide.bs.modal** - This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.
>
> **hidden.bs.modal**   - This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to
>   complete).

Answer (score 1):

try to attach jquery files at the beginning, that work for me..

new:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

old:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```